# Fixed position 100% height element on touch device (iOS) and resize of height

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, web

I am testing a responsive site on some iOS devices (iPad, iPhone), and am noticing the following issue.

I have a left sidebar that is styled as follows:

```
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 60px;
height: 100%
```

When I first load the page, the Safari or generally any browser address bar is ~ 100px, and then when the user scrolls down the address bar collapses to something closer to ~40px.

However, in between the time when the user starts scrolling and when the page stops scrolling there is the 60px of gap that I can't fill with the same color as the element and thus the background-color of body shows through. Here is a screenshot to demonstrate:

When page loads - looks good: http://f.cl.ly/items/2C3W1N3e1k1w0P2v051A/load.png

When scrolling: http://f.cl.ly/items/2S3v3Y3b3y3e3l251J0v/scrolling.jpg

I've tried to make the height of the element ~60px extra in height to make up for this or add padding, but nothing seems to fix this.

On page load...

```
if ($('html').hasClass('touch')) {
  var winHeight = window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight || document.body.clientHeight;
  $('.sidebar').find('.strip').height(winHeight + 60);
}
```

Any suggestions or people experience similar?

Comment: common problem that IOS applies delay on position:fixed until user has stopped, I think it's corrected in IOS 8 but IOS 8 has other issues with position fixed. I have never seen any correction for this in the last 2 years.

Comment: Did you resolve this problem? I am facing the exact same issue.

Comment: No, unfortunately I did not find a solution.